# Determining the position of a box (e.g.) on a page

Tags: boxes, positioning

Suppose I have some .tex code like this

```
...
bla bla \framebox{Hello World} bla bla
...
```

I want to read out the position (left and top or bottom, in `pt`s) of the framebox on the page, and store in, say, variables `\myleft`, `\myright`.

It would also be enough to read out the current position on the page.
(I want to highlight the box later in another program, so I need to know its absolute position in the produced pdf.)

Synctex seems to be able to do that, so it should be possible... but how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `\zsavepos` macro of the [zref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/) package. Note you need to LaTeX twice before you have the position accurately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}

\zsavepos{XY}\fbox{Testing }
\medskip

\zposx{XY}, \zposy{XY} 

\def\X{\FPdiv\result{\zposx{XY}}{65536}\result}

\def\Y{\FPdiv\result{\zposy{XY}}{65536}\result}

\X, \Y
\end{document}
```

Edit: show minimal using `fp` package for calculations.

Comment: That works very well, thanks for the very quick answer!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the functionality of TikZ and its `remember picture` option. It needs two compile runs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\tikz[remember picture]\node(x){\framebox{Test}};
\lipsum[2-3]

% Later
% There are better ways to do this, I'm sure:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path let \p0 = (x.north west) in
  % \x0, \y0 hold the position from the lower left page corner
  [/utils/exec={\message{x = \x0, y = \y0}}]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code helped me as well, though I'll go with Yiannis' answer.

Comment: @Thomas: You are welcome, and no problem, `zref` seems to be the right way to do it. I didn't know it before by myself.

Answer (score 4):

It needs two pdflatex runs

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\begin{document}

\ldots

bla bla \zsavepos{fbox}\framebox{Hello World} bla bla

\ldots

the fbox starts at (\zposx{fbox}sp;\zposy{fbox}sp), which is the same
as (\the\numexpr \zposx{fbox}/65536\relax pt; 
    \the\numexpr \zposy{fbox}/65536\relax pt), 
always measured from the left and bottom of the page

\end{document}
```